# Where can I find free training tools like detailed annotated chess openings, middle games and endgames in the PGN format?

Tags: opening, learning, software, tactics, pgn

I have decided to study chess after playing it leisurely for a while. I looked at some online chess courses like the ones offered by Igor Smirnov at the Remote Chess Academy, but these options seem to be quite expensive ($700+). I looked at one of these courses that my friend purchased and it contained some openings that were annotated and showed variations of an opening:
[image: This image is a snippet from one of the PGN files offered in the course covering the French Defence]
I was wondering whether there are freely available resources like the one in the picture below that have detailed annotations of openings, middle games, endgames, tactics, etc. If so, where would I be able to download them?

Alternatively, is there is any free/inexpensive software that acts as a trainer of some sort where one can practice openings, middle game strategy, end games, tactics, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look a [chess.com](http://www.chess.com/) forums where people share a lot of PGN games.
[pgnmentor.com](http://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html) offers PGN sorted with openings, middle game themes and endgame themes. If you are looking for an all in one platform, chessbase is the best so far, a bit expensive but will serve you well.